# Bootstrap Toggle Value Passing to Codeigniter 3 Issue

Tags: codeigniter-3

In my app, I have customer form with bootstrap toggle button from [Link](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/kv8ER)

in View my HTML code is

```
input type="checkbox" name="" class="onoffswitch3-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch3"  data-format="Y-m-d"  required >
    <label class="onoffswitch3-label" for="myonoffswitch3">
        <span class="onoffswitch3-inner">
            <span class="onoffswitch3-active"><span class="onoffswitch3-switch" id="onoffswitch3-switch">Active</span></span>
            <span class="onoffswitch3-inactive"><span class="onoffswitch3-switch" id="onoffswitch3 the switch">Inactive</span></span>
        </span>
    </label>
```

I In DB I have field 'status'

```
0 => Inactive
1 => Active
```

How can I assign value to .onoffswitch3-checkbox? I have tried a lot but no success.

I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" class="onoffswitch3-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch3"  <?= $value == true?
 echo "checked": ""; ?>>

Comment: if($('.onoffswitch3').prop("checked") == true){
       
       $('.onoffswitch3-checkbox').val('1');
       alert( $('.onoffswitch3-checkbox').val() );
    }else{
       $('.onoffswitch3-checkbox').val('0');
    }

But the problem is condition is matching but I am unable to assign value.???

Comment: i dont think you can assign 0 checkboxes do not have a value if tey are not checked

Answer (score 0):

I am not shore you can assign value of 0 to checkbox, unchecked checkboxes do not have a value.

Here is how you check / uncheck checkbox..

```
 //Javascript
        document.getElementById("onoffswitch3-switch").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("onoffswitch3-switch").checked = false;

        //jquery 
        $(".onoffswitch3-checkbox").prop("checked", true);
        $(".onoffswitch3-checkbox").prop("checked", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you all for trying to help.

I have implemented javascript but behaving not normally

but I have implemented following one line code

```
<input type="checkbox" name="statusupd" class="statusupd" value="<?php echo $employee->status;?>" <?php if ( $employee->status == 1) { echo 'checked disabled'; } ;?>
```

Thanks again to all of you.